# Are Webpack SASS Source-maps Broken?

Tags: webpack, sass, source-maps, sass-loader

I'm evaluating Webpack as a replacement for Grunt in my company's projects. Everything seems great, apart from SASS source-maps which point to incorrect files for project stylesheets and have the incorrect paths for library ones. For example, using the following minimal configuration, the sole rule is attributed to Bootstrap's `_reboot.scss` and `node_modules` is shown as being nested under `src`.

Have I set something up wrong, or is this an actual problem? If so, does anyone know which project I should be submitting a bug report to?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ],

    entry: "./src/main.scss",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**src/main.scss**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

body {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  test: /\.s?css$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        outputStyle: 'compressed', // This fixed the source maps
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

EDIT: I'm usinge `devtool: 'source-map'` in production and `devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map'` in development.

I don't fully understand the forces at play quite yet, but if you are looking to have your scss source maps point to the `@import` files with proper line numbers, this works.

The reason the line numbers are incorrect, in my case, I noticed sass complies something like

```
body {
   background: black;
}
```

to

```
body {
   background: black; }
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't too helpful, please try and explain your code.

Comment: @GKE Assuming it works, there's not much that could be added to the answer unless jameygleason is familiar with the inner workings of the software; it's just one of those quirks where a setting which shouldn't have a certain affect does. You probably couldn't even tell which developers should be sent the bug report without a lot of work.

Comment: @jameygleason Many thanks. Afraid I've no idea when I'll get a chance to test this, since my sudio's settled on Grunt for the time being, but fingers crossed it sorts the chaining issue.